# How can I make a div stick to the top of the screen once it's been scrolled to the current div header

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a div, that is situated beneath a block of content but that once the page has been scrolled enough to contact its top boundary, becomes fixed in place and scrolls with the page. I know I've seen at least one example of this online but I cannot remember it for the life of me.

http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/11/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(window).scroll(function () {
     });
 });
```

I am trying to put this content as shown in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HQS8s/

but not sure of how to implement this , could you please  let me know how to do this ??

Comment: StickyJS is a jQuery plugin you might want to give a try, it does just that: http://stickyjs.com/

Comment: Just this functionality shouldn't be too much code though. But what sticky element are we talking about exactly - where should it be located?

Comment: i am not sure of what you are mentioning , i guess its place where the data should be appended , it can be anywhere (above class named data in  the mentioned fiddle )

Answer (score 0):

i have modified your jsfiddle as follows (it is what i understand from your question spare me if i wrong)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var $window = $(window),
         $headerBar = $('#headerBar'),
         $headerBarAnchor = $('#headerBarAnchor');

      $(window).scroll(function () {
         var window_top = $window.scrollTop();
         var div_top = $headerBarAnchor.offset().top;
         if (window_top > div_top) {
            // Make the div sticky.
            $headerBar.addClass('stick');
            $headerBarAnchor.height($headerBar.height());
         }
         else {
            // Unstick the div.
            $headerBar.removeClass('stick');
            $headerBarAnchor.height(0);
        }     
      });
 });
```

check http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/12/

Comment: Thank you very much , if i am scrolling in Header 2 , Header must not be visible . is there any confusing ??

Comment: do you mean individually when scrolling in header 2 then header 1 hide and when scroling in header 1 then header 2 hide like this

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding , i need a similar site as shown below  http://slinky.iclanzan.com/